# How should I properly seed C++11 std::default_random_engine?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

According to [this](http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/cpp-seeding-surprises.html) post, intuitive seeding with `std::random_device` may not produce the expected results. In particular, if the Mersenne Twister engine is used, not all the initialization states can be reached. Using seed_seq doesn't helper either, since it is not a bijection.

This all, as far as I understand, means that not the `std::uniform_int_distribution` will not really be uniform - because not all seed values are possible.

I'd like to simply generate a couple of random numbers. While this is a really interesting topic which I will certainly devote some of my free time, many people may not have this possibility.

So the question is: how should I properly seed the `std::default_random_engine` so that it simply does what I expect?

Comment: Stephan T. Lavavej, the lead maintainer of Microsoft's STL implmentation recommends, MT19937 in this talk. Worth watching too https://channel9.msdn.com/events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: @Some programmer dude the default_ seed used if you just default construct is hardcoded as `5489u` (for mt19937). A fixed hardcoded seed is rarely what you want.

Comment: I think a `uniform_int_distribution` will still be uniform however you seed it. But better seeding can reduce chances of getting the same sequence of uniformly distributed values.

Comment: How secure do you need these numbers to be? Are they for rolling dice in a game, or for some cryptographic purpose like generating a secure key? If it’s the first one, any sort of seeding is probably good enough.

Comment: @DanielH Yes, and if it is for cryptographic purposes then a pseudo random number generator is not good enough anyway.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Probably, but there’s a bunch of stuff in between; there’s a good example in the paper where you want high-quality seeding but don’t care enough for an hrng

Comment: I don't think `std::default_random_engine` is meant to be anything other than a `toy` as it doesn't give any guarantees. The good thing about the *mersenne twister* is that it tells you the size of its internal state giving you information as to how big a seed you need. I don't know if you can do that with the *default_random_engine*.

Answer (score 6):

A `uniform_int_distribution` will still be uniform however you seed it. But better seeding can reduce chances of getting the same sequence of uniformly distributed values.

I think for most purposes using a `std::seed_seq` with about 8 random 32bit ints from `std::random_device` should be sufficient. It is not perfect, for the reasons given in the post you linked but if you need really secure numbers for cryptographic purposes you shouldn't really be using a pseudo random number generator anyway:

```
constexpr std::size_t SEED_LENGTH = 8;

std::array<uint_fast32_t, SEED_LENGTH> generateSeedData() {
  std::array<uint_fast32_t, SEED_LENGTH> random_data;
  std::random_device random_source;
  std::generate(random_data.begin(), random_data.end(), std::ref(random_source));
  return random_data;
}

std::mt19937 createEngine() {
  auto random_data = generateSeedData();
  std::seed_seq seed_seq(random_data.begin(), random_data.end());
  return std::mt19937{ seed_seq };
}
```

Comment: Why 8 and not 6 or 10? And why can I feel safe using std::random_device here if I did not before?